# Navigating multi-dimensional object to match key with only ES5, multiple Object.key and .map

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-5

I am attempting to interrogate a multi-dimensional object and return part of the object based on a variable available to me. I do not have access to many of ES6's object and array methods.

My object to interrogate looks like:

```
const myObj = {
    blue: {
      three: {
          star: { 
              foo: "this object is what I want",
              foo2: "this object is what I want"
          }
      }
    } 
}
```

As you can see there are three layers to this. I do not know what any of the keys may be with the exception of `star`. I know I want to return the value of this key if it's available.

In order to return the object for the key `star` I am currently using `Object.keys().map()` three times, which works but I feel like there must be a simpler solution. Below is what I have:

```
  return Object.keys(myObj).map(function(colour) {
    Object.keys(myObj[colour]).map(function(number) {
      Object.keys(myObj[colour][number]).map(function(shape){
        if (myObj[colour][number][shape] === "star") {
          return myObj[colour][number][shape];
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

Is there something else I can use to step through this object until I hit my matching key? And then return the value of that key?

Answer (score 1):

```
const myObj = {
    blue: {
      three: {
          star: { 
              foo: "this object is what I want",
              foo2: "this object is what I want"
          }
      }
    } 
}
```

You can iterate over all properties and check if that property is, what you want.. than you can build array from them or whatever you like. :)

```
const seeker = function (object) {

  for (let property in object)
  {
      if (property === 'star')
      {
          console.log(property, object[property])
      }

      if (object[property] instanceof Object)
        seeker(object[property])
  }
}
```

Comment: I came with something similar than you [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pkwayusn/18/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try this:

```js
function recursive(myObj) {
    const result = [];
    for (const key in myObj) {
        if (key === 'star') {
            result.push(myObj[key]);
        }
        if (typeof myObj[key] === 'object') {
            result.push(recursive(myObj[key]).reduce((acc, val) => acc.concat(val), []));
        }
    }
    return result.reduce((acc, val) => acc.concat(val), []);
}
```